# How do I cancel all queries for a particular user in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know that, in the docs, it says I can cancel all queries from a session with this command

`SELECT SYSTEM$CANCEL_ALL_QUERIES(<session id>)`

What's the equivalent for canceling all queries from a particular user? I have a user where every query comes from a different session ID and I'd like an easy way to abort the queries from this user. I'm referring to a Snowflake database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rather non-obviously, you need an ALTER USER statement:

```
ALTER USER [ IF EXISTS ] < name > ABORT ALL QUERIES
```

Permissions to be able to run this:

```
GRANT CREATE USER ON ACCOUNT TO <role>
```

Comment: I believe the CREATE privilege enables the ALTER privilege as well - so any role that has the CREATE USER privilege should be able to run this ALTER USER statement. If your role does not have this privilege then you'd need to use a role that does to grant it to your role (obviously you can't grant yourself privileges, unless you are using ACCOUNTADMIN). You grant it by running the appropriate SQL statement in a worksheet: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#grant-privileges-to-role

Comment: Not sure why you were trying to run that statement, you need to be running GRANT CREATE USER TO <role>

Comment: Sorry, it should probably be GRANT CREATE USER ON ACCOUNT TO <role>